# React Native mobx: Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm using mobx as state management for my react-native app, I'm modifying a simple array of ids like this:

```
let copyy = userStore.unreadChatIds;
copyy.push(e.message.chat_id);
userStore.setUnreadChatIds(copyy);
```

However I'm getting this mobx warning, I don't know why I'm getting it since I'm using makeAutoObservable in my mobx store!

```
[MobX] Since strict-mode is enabled, changing (observed) observable values without using an action is not allowed. Tried to modify: UserStore@1.unreadChatIds
```

My store

```
export class UserStore
{
    constructor()
    {
        makeAutoObservable(this);
        
unreadChatIds=[];

setUnreadChatIds(payload)
    {
        this.unreadChatIds = payload;
    }
}
```

Why am I getting this error and how can I solve it? afaik if using makeAutoObservable and use my setter method as action I'm not changing mobx state directly.

Answer (score 0):

This warning occurs as you are modifying the userStore.unreadChatIds directly.

To resolve this, you should modifying the value via action

```
userStore.addChatId(e.message.chat_id);
```

Store

```
export class UserStore
{
    constructor()
    {
        makeAutoObservable(this, {
        unreadChatIds: observable,
        setUnreadChatIds: action,
        addChatId: action,
    });
        
unreadChatIds=[];

setUnreadChatIds(payload)
    {
        this.unreadChatIds = payload;
    }

addChatId(id)
 {
   this.unreadChatIds.push(id);
 }
}
```